# Multiplying unsymmetrical data frames in R

Tags: r

I have these two different size dataframes I want to multiply.

```
a<- data.frame(Var1=c("a","a","b","b","d","d"), Var2=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),Var3=c(3,4,5,6,7,4))
b<- data.frame(Var1=c("a","b"), Var2=c(123,234),Var3=c(9,8))
```

I want to do something like this

```
    apply(a, 1, FUN = function(x) {
      x[2:3]*b[b$Var1==x[1],2:3]
    }
)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What is the best way to get a dataframe whith multiplied columns (Var2 and Var3) between the two dataframes?

Comment: When you do `apply` it coerces everything to a `matrix` with only one type of data - in this case character strings. That's why you get your error because you are trying to do `"a" * "1"` essentially.

Comment: Do you want to multiply col 2 * col 2 and col 3 * col 3 and then add them for each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match` the `Var1` keys, and then multiply the corresponding parts:

```
sel <- match(a$Var1, b$Var1)
a[!is.na(sel), 2:3] <- a[!is.na(sel), 2:3] * b[na.omit(sel), 2:3]

#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    a  123   27
#2    a  123   36
#3    b  468   40
#4    b  468   48
#5    d    3    7
#6    d    3    4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a join from `data.table`

```
nm1 <- names(a)[-1]
setDT(a)[b, (nm1) := Map(`*`, mget(nm1), mget(paste0("i.", nm1))), on = .(Var1)]
a
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
#1:    a  123   27
#2:    a  123   36
#3:    b  468   40
#4:    b  468   48
#5:    d    3    7
#6:    d    3    4
```